# How can I target both :-webkit-full-screen and :moz-full-screen at the same time?

Tags: css

This works:

```
:-webkit-full-screen {
    ...
}
```

And so does this:

```
:-moz-full-screen {
    ...
}
```

But when I do this, the styles don't get applied in Chrome or Firefox:

```
:-webkit-full-screen, :-moz-full-screen {
    ...
}
```

How do I target both?

Comment: @TrevorDixon LESS will help you - `.mixin() { ... } ::-webkit-full-screen { .mixin} ::-moz-full-screen { .mixin }`

Comment: @Trevor Dixon: Another reason why prefixes don't seem like such a good idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rob is right about this being a duplicate, but the short version is that Firefox says ":-webkit-full-screen? That's garbage; I'm throwing out this whole selector", and Chrome says the same about :-moz-full-screen. You need to copy the whole thing out for each selector.

Answer (score 0):

Can't be done. You need two declarations. Browsers will ignore selectors they don't recognize.